# MYSQL - Can't access my databases

Tags: mysql, database, root

**Problem has been solved using:**

```
update user set host='%' where user='root' and host='localhost';
flush privileges;
```

**Original question:**

I can't see any of my databases.

I can see them physically (via any File Explorer) in the `MySql\Bin\Data` folder (*mysql,test,performance_schema, my_data,databesttest, xyz*).

But when I access via  `mysql -u -root` and `SHOW databases;`  I can only see `test` and `performance_schema` databases.

(My commands also don't work: " Error (1044) (42000) Access denied for user ''@localhost". )

I've also tried logging in with `mysql -u -root -p` (and <kbd>Enter</kbd> when prompted for pass), but the problems persist.

Comment: Make sure that the files and directories under `\mysql(version)\bin\data` are accessible to the MySQL Service/Process

Comment: Restart MySQL and look at the log files of MySQL for errors